# How do I fix my code for selection sort?

Tags: c++

This is my code for implementing selection sort, but the output is not in the correct order. Can someone please tell me where the problem is?

So this is my code for implementing a selection sort:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class sort {
public:
    void ssort(string[], int[]);
    void print(string[], int);

};

// sorting function
// is the problem here?
void sort::ssort(string arr[], int numarray[]) {
    int min;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        min = i;
        //Loop through the array to find it
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 9; ++j)
        {
            if (numarray[j] < numarray[min])
            {
                //Found new minimum position, if present
                min = j;
            }
        }
        //Swap the values
        swap(arr[i], arr[min]);
    }
}

void sort::print(string arr[], int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

//main function
main() {
    sort s;
    int num = 8;
    string arr[8];
    string array[8];
    int numarray[8];


    cout << "Input 8 strings to sort: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        getline(cin, arr[i]);
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        array[i] = arr[i].substr(0, 1);

        if (array[i] == "a")
            numarray[i] = 1;
        if (array[i] == "b")
            numarray[i] = 2;
        if (array[i] == "c")
            numarray[i] = 3;
        if (array[i] == "d")
            numarray[i] = 4;
        if (array[i] == "e")
            numarray[i] = 5;
        if (array[i] == "f")
            numarray[i] = 6;
        if (array[i] == "g")
            numarray[i] = 7;
        if (array[i] == "h")
            numarray[i] = 8;
        if (array[i] == "i")
            numarray[i] = 9;
        if (array[i] == "j")
            numarray[i] = 10;
        if (array[i] == "k")
            numarray[i] = 11;
        if (array[i] == "l")
            numarray[i] = 12;
        if (array[i] == "m")
            numarray[i] = 13;
        if (array[i] == "n")
            numarray[i] = 14;
        if (array[i] == "o")
            numarray[i] = 15;
        if (array[i] == "p")
            numarray[i] = 16;
        if (array[i] == "q")
            numarray[i] = 17;
        if (array[i] == "r")
            numarray[i] = 18;
        if (array[i] == "s")
            numarray[i] = 19;
        if (array[i] == "t")
            numarray[i] = 20;
        if (array[i] == "u")
            numarray[i] = 21;
        if (array[i] == "v")
            numarray[i] = 22;
        if (array[i] == "w")
            numarray[i] = 23;
        if (array[i] == "x")
            numarray[i] = 24;
        if (array[i] == "y")
            numarray[i] = 25;
        if (array[i] == "z")
            numarray[i] = 26;

    }

    cout << "The Initial Input: " << endl;
    s.print(arr, num);

    s.ssort(arr, numarray);

    cout << endl << "The input after sorting: " << endl;
    s.print(arr, num);
}
```

what can I do about this?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: What is the input and current vs expected output? I don't dabble in C++ often, but I have to imagine there is a library that handles exactly what it is you're looking for. Is there any reason you're trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do it manually

Comment: You're sorting, or attempting to sort, the strings on their first character alone. Is that intentional?

Comment: "It's all wrong" is so broad as to make this debug-my-code request an unsuitable question for this site. How will it help anyone else one day?

Answer (score 3):

I identified three issues with a quick reading of your code:

- First the inner loop condition is wrong

  ```
  void sort::ssort(string arr[], int numarray[]) {
    int min;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
      min = i;
      //Loop through the array to find it
      for (int j = i + 1; j < 9; ++j) // Out-of-bound access on j == 8
  ```
- Second: your `ssort` function will only sort strings according to their first character. It is not really sorting the strings.
- Third (and this is a big algorithmic error): you're not swapping the `numarray` vector elements after you swapped your `arr` elements. That means all the swaps after the first one (where the indices are in the right position) are potentially **wrong**.

  ```
  void sort::ssort(string arr[], int numarray[]) {
    int min;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
      min = i;
      //Loop through the array to find it
      for (int j = i + 1; j < 8; ++j)
      {
        if (numarray[j] < numarray[min])
        {
            //Found new minimum position, if present
          min = j;
        }
      }
      //Swap the values
      swap(arr[i], arr[min]);
      // Also swap the comparison values
      swap(numarray[i], numarray[min]); // <-- this is missing!
    }
  }
  ```

Tips to improve:

- Grab a good algorithms book and study it
- Grab a good debugger and use it

Answer (score 1):

You should update `numarray` as well as `arr` and mustn't access out of bounds.

```
void sort::ssort(string arr[], int numarray[]) {
    int min;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        min = i;
        //Loop through the array to find it
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 8; ++j) // fix : 9 -> 8
        {
            if (numarray[j] < numarray[min])
            {
                //Found new minimum position, if present
                min = j;
            }
        }
        //Swap the values
        swap(arr[i], arr[min]);
        swap(numarray[i], numarray[min]); // add this line
    }
}
```